# Urban Airship config Android app manifest file

Tags: android, manifest, urbanairship.com

I want to use an Urban Airship service in my Android app.
I've already registered a sender email following [this](http://urbanairship.com/docs/getting_started_android_push.html) tutorial.

Now when I've got my C2DM AUTH_TOKEN I've created an app on my UA account and pasted the TOKEN along with the package name of my app (which is "com.neo.ovs") .

Now onCreate method I've added those lines of code :

```
PushManager.enablePush();
PushPreferences prefs = PushManager.shared().getPreferences();
Logger.info("My Application onCreate - App APID: " + prefs.getPushId());
```

Now of course I get an error becouse of various permissions I didn't write in my manifest.xml file.

But I'm a bit confused about the package names and prefixes I should alter following [this](http://urbanairship.com/docs/android-client-push.html#androidmanifest-xml) manifest example.

how should my manifest look ?

write now it looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.neo.ovs"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="OVS" >
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="OVS"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Entry for MyListActivity.class -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.neo.ovs.MyListActivity"
            android:label="My List Activity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".VideoScreen"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="Video View Demo"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: http://urbanairship.com/docs/android-client-push.html

Comment: Thank you for your response but I've already seen that and many other relevant topics before posting this question.My confusion is about package prefix. Where should I change it to com.urbanairship.push.sample ? or should I ?